# Avoid an excessive DOM size - jQuery.mmenu

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, mmenu, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I want to implement a nice menue like https://mmenujs.com/

But I noticed it is causing a new warning in [google pages speed:](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmmenujs.com%2F&tab=desktop)

> Avoid an excessive DOM size - 959 nodes

What are these nodes and how may I modify the plugin to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a line of code, that is, an html element, for example  ...

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/reduce-the-scope-and-complexity-of-style-calculations

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.